# Run local bash script on multiple remote machine

Tags: bash, scripting

I have below bash script,every time i want to create a user i need to copy this script to server and run it.

Is there any thing we can do so that this script fetches the IP's from a hosts.txt file(running script on multiple server's)one by one and create user on server.Also,we need to be root to run this script.

1.ask for password once and use it in script for rest of the script where ever necessary.
2.login as normal user.
3.become a root user and run the script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script to Add User

read -p 'Please Enter The Username To Add: ' name
echo "$name" > /tmp/userlist.txt
clear
echo -e "Hallo $name\nYour Name Is Added To The List."
userfile=/tmp/userlist.txt
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
for user in $username
do
useradd $user -N -s /bin/bash
usermod -aG sudo $user
passwd $user
done
echo "=================================="

echo "User $name Have Been Created."

echo "=================================="
tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: You are ready to start using a configuration management/orchestration system, such as ansible. Consider making a simple ansible [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) and [inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) to [add a user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html). (Probably someone has already published one online.) It will probably take longer than five minutes but you will learn a lot that will help you automate other tasks too.

Comment: @michael : Thanks you.Yes i know about ansilble and we are shifting to it and it will take some time.Meanwhile , we need this script

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the script and run it from a centralized point create a general provisioning script in charge of copying and executing

1. Create an array list, in this case I used a file called hostList.active
2. Set the only argument to be the script you're trying to copy & execute on the remote server. (In this case it will run in the remote machines home directory)

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   while read box; do
     ping -c 1 -w 1 -q $box > /dev/null
     if (test $? = 0); then
         echo "***************************************************************"
         echo $box
         scp $1 $box:~/.
         ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no -X $box "~/$1"
      else echo $box is not responding to ping
          echo $box >> hostList.notdone
      fi
   done < hostList.active
   ```

I placed 2 test servers in my array list file (hostList.active) and it connected to both, copied the script and executed it.

```
   ./copyandrun.sh bogus.sh

   ***************************************************************
    tsweb
    bogus.sh                                                            100%   36     0.0KB/s   00:00    
    Running a Test
    ***************************************************************
    tsdb
    bogus.sh                                                            100%   36     0.0KB/s   00:00    
    Running a Test
```

Ensure the script your copying has proper permissions to be able to be executed by whatever user your copying it over as.