# Multiple same user creation with same username on multiple server

Tags: bash, scripting

Below is the script which i use to create single user on server(I use another scpect script to copy below script on server and run script),But i want to create multiple user.

So,only once i will enter username on line 4 and it will create multiple user with increment user1,user2 and so on...

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script to Add User

tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
read -p 'Please Enter The Username To Add: ' name
echo "$name" > /tmp/userlist.txt
clear
echo -e "Hello $name\nYour Name Is Added To The List."
userfile=/tmp/userlist.txt
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
for user in $username
do
useradd $user -N -s /bin/bash
usermod -aG sudo $user
passwd $user
#echo "AllowUsers ${user}" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/tui/tui $user/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/$user.*$user/$user/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/tui/tui $user/g" /etc/security/access.conf
done
echo "=================================="

echo "User $name Have Been Created."

echo "=================================="
tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: You would make your live a lot easier if you would use a configuration management system like Ansible, Chef, Puppet etc.

Comment: Hey @Gerald, I know about the tools.Tools are being set up till then we have to use script. Kindly help

Comment: You can install ansible on your laptop.  It doesn't require "setup" that most admins can't handle in a few minutes.  Bash is wonderful, but in this case it should be used to invoke ansible.

Comment: I answered this 2 weeks ago: https://serverfault.com/questions/1032355/run-local-bash-script-on-multiple-remote-machine/1032770#1032770

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

````
#Script to Add User

tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
read -p 'Please Enter The Username To Add: ' name

for COUNTER in {1..4};
do
        echo $name$COUNTER >> /tmp/userlist.txt
        echo -e "Hello $name$COUNTER\nYour Name Is Added To The List."
done

clear

userfile=/tmp/userlist.txt
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
for user in $username
do
useradd $user -N -s /bin/bash
usermod -aG sudo $user
passwd $user
#echo "AllowUsers ${user}" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/tui/tui $user/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/$user.*$user/$user/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i "s/tui/tui $user/g" /etc/security/access.conf
done
echo "=================================="

echo "User $name Have Been Created."

echo "=================================="
tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1```
````